# android activity containing viewpager opening slowly

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, rendering, viewpage

I am trying to navigate from one activity to another. The second activity has a viewpager having three fragments. Two of the fragments have lots of views on it and one of it has less views. I tried keeping only one fragment in the viewpager that has lot of views. It took some time to load. I tried another one with lot of views. It also took time to load. But when i kept the fragment that had less views it took less time. If i load all at once it again takes lot of time to load. I first had lot of view hierarchies on both the fragment, but i removed them all ultimately using table layout. The activity is rendering slow.
fragment 1:

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TableRow style="@style/TableRowStyle">

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow style="@style/TableRowStyle">

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/white" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow style="@style/TableRowStyle">

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                </TableRow>


                <TableRow style="@style/TableRowStyle">

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"
                        android:background="@color/white" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/ll_nfo1"
                    style="@style/TableRowStyle"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow android:id="@+id/ll_nfo2"
                    style="@style/TableRowStyle"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow style="@style/BidOfferTableRowStyle">

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow style="@style/BidOfferTableRowStyle">

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow style="@style/BidOfferTableRowStyle">

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow style="@style/BidOfferTableRowStyle">

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                </TableRow>

                <TableRow style="@style/BidOfferTableRowStyle">

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                </TableRow>

            </TableLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_40">

        <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_h_first"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view_line3_left"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_h_first"
            android:background="@color/mainbg_lightblue" />

        <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment 3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                />

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp">

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/day_spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="34dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/limit_spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="34dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/buy_spinner"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="34dp" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sub_qty"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_qty"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/add_qty"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sub_price"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_pricevalue"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/add_price"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sub_dis_qty"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_dis_qty"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/add_dis_qty"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"/>


        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp">

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sub_tri_price"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/et_triggerPrice"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/add_tri_price"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.3" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/ch_stopLoss"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/ch_IOC"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <com.intmilli.imobile.Views.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_placeOrderBtn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

As i was saying fragment 1 and 3 are taking lots of time. Can someone help to solve this issue thanks!

Comment: you have quite large content in both scrollviews. Try using RecyclerView for that

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i haven't given the whole layout actually due to stackoverflow's restriction on having only 30000 characters. so i had to remove some of the parts. the data is such that i cannot use recycler view but only layouts.

Comment: can you mention logcats when you open fragment 1 and 3?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta no such relative log data while navigating

Answer (score 2):

- **Weights** are **not good** for much use. I seen you have used **too much** `android:layout_weight` in your layout. That cause slow loading layout. Because it needs adjust views according to device screen.

  So don't use too much weights and go with [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative) or [ConstraintLayout.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout)
- Don't write any logics, data fetching, views management inside `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`.
- Do all `findViewById()` in `onViewCreated()` of Fragments. Also read [Fragment Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment) for better understanding.
- If you are calling API then **call** it with **some delay** in `onViewCreated()`. It will let view created first then set data received from API.
- Note that you are **not doing** any **long operation** or logics in UI or Main Thread. That should be done in [Worker Thread](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads) like [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) or new Thread.

Comment: This didn't work ConstraintLayout took double the time. i removed the table layout and just used ConstraintLayout. It took twice the time to open another activity

Comment: Are you also filling some data in your view currently?

Comment: ya its coming from server, but i am using sockets, so there's no issue of response and all, i have changed the ui twice now, constraint layout taking the highest time

Comment: Did you try disabling server implementation once. You will know if its UI issue or data filling issue.

Comment: disabled all the services, it still takes time, oncreateview methods of both fragments are taking long average 140ms both are taking, some times fragment 1 takes 200 ms too, i got these values from android profiler. Activity takes on average 2/2.5 secs to open

Comment: What are things you are doing in `onCreateView`? Can you post `CustomTextView`? What are you doing in that. Can you try with regular TextView?

Comment: Theres nothing in onCreateView, all the initialization and logic starts from onviewcreated, customtextview only consist of fonts settings

Comment: Can you check with empty `onViewCreated()`? To be sure if that's an layout issue or code issue.

Comment: so i created an empty layout file without any views and inflated on both the fragments, guess out the navigation was faster

Comment: I was assuming you to check your existing layout with no server logic.

Comment: disabled all the services, it still takes time, oncreateview methods of both fragments are taking long average 140ms both are taking, some times fragment 1 takes 200 ms too, i got these values from android profiler. Activity takes on average 2/2.5 secs to open

Comment: Can you set your ViewPager with 500 millisecond delay. It will properly let animate navigation drawer.

Comment: ya i did that, but here no one wants it like that way. No one wants a workaround actually

Comment: This is not also a good idea to load a large UI just on replacing Fragment. It is liek doing heavy work on `onCreateView()`. Because UI is inflated on UI thread, so it is hanging the navigation drawer.

Comment: @Khemraj i know it late to response to this.but if replace again when backpress, maybe need to try to save the instance of fragment and not to load data again.